# Adding paragraph using confluence Rest API

Tags: jira-rest-api

I have document in the atlas, to which I need to add another paragraph, but not to remove other text, so not to update the page because when I am updating the page it removes the other text. I am using postman for API calls in JSON format. Any suggestions on it?

So, I would like to add another text to the body of the page. Like paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the content in the storage format and add the paragraph where ever you want.  Then update your page with the new storage.